# Android studio on Ubuntu doesnt connects to API server

Tags: networking, server, android, android-studio, android-sdk

So I am working on a app which is created by a fellow programmer who is now not available. When I run the app via android studio it starts normally but when I click on login button on the login screen after filling my email and password I get error that "Unable to connect to the server" what could be the issue. I tried to surf some websites on the emulated device and they are working fine. I also tried to surf the website which hosts the API and that is also opening. Any directions in this regard will be helpful.

My AndroidManifest.xml is asking for follwing permissiosn

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
and many more
```

Comment: Does this happen on any other os?

Comment: I haven't tried because I do not have android studio on other computers

Comment: Try it on a real device then

Comment: its working fine on real device I have a compiled app and its running smoothly I just want to make some changes and these changes are in inner pages

Comment: You also may get more answers on the [Programmers Stack Exchange Site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Does the manifest file of your project allow network access?
You need to have the following entry in AndroidManifest.xml to enable network access from your app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For details please have a look at:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

If you have an anrdoid device at hands it is the best option to connect it with your computer and activate debug mode which enables you to use debugging while running your app on the phone (instead of the emulator). For more datails see:
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: added my code in the question